# Is currently unable to handle, 500 HTTP error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Thanks to everyone for answering all the questions being asked here!

I am new to Magento 2.1.7 and I have Cpanel and WHM Installed on CentOS 7 and I searched a lot for HTTP 500 error to my Magento site but none of them are working for me. I tried installing PHP7 and Perl Modules PHP-FPM and a lot of things I have been doing for 10 days but still helpless. Then I came to know that all your developers can help me once I get the error code so I got on developer mode and found this error code.

Kindly request to help me with it or if anyone want my server details to set it up I am ready to do that as I am noob in the tech world. Thanks in Advance

Please visit my website for the error code. I don't know how to insert error code here

```
Zend\Stdlib\Exception\RuntimeException: No wrapper found supporting "UTF-8" in /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/StringUtils.php:135
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/Hostname.php(1336): Zend\Stdlib\StringUtils::getWrapper('UTF-8') 
#1 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(287): Zend\Validator\Hostname->isValid('www.roundandbol...') 
#2 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(86): Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->setServer(Object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)) 
#3 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(130): Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct() 
#4 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieReader), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils), NULL) 
#5 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieReader), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Route\ConfigInterface\Proxy), Object(Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager), NULL, Array) 
#6 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) 
#7 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...') 
#8 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...') 
#9 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'request', 'Magento\\Framewo...') 
#10 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array) 
#11 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...') 
#12 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...') 
#13 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'logger', 'Magento\\Framewo...') 
#14 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array) 
#15 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) 
#16 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(195): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) 
#17 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(159): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->_applyDecorators(Object(Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope)) 
#18 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->create(Array) 
#19 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->_initialize() 
#20 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/FrontendPool.php(84): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->get('default') 
#21 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/Config.php(49): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool->get('config') 
#22 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config->_getFrontend() 
#23 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader.php(66): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->load('global::DiConfi...') 
#24 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(77): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader->load('global') 
#25 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(194): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager(Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer), Array) 
#26 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(385): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) 
#27 /home/roundandbold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(232): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->initObjectManager() 
#28 /home/roundandbold/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\\Framewo...') 
#29 {main}
```

Comment: website name is : www.roundandbold.com

Answer (score 0):

You can see your error message here:

> No wrapper found supporting "UTF-8"

It looks like you are missing one or more PHP extensions for UTF-8 support. Please follow the instructions in the Magento DevDocs for [preparing your server to support Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html#php-centos-7).

Specifically, step #3 in the instructions for *"To install PHP 7 on CentOS 6 or 7"* which lists the required PHP extensions:

```shell
yum -y install php70u php70u-pdo php70u-mysqlnd php70u-opcache php70u-xml php70u-mcrypt php70u-gd php70u-devel php70u-mysql php70u-intl php70u-mbstring php70u-bcmath php70u-json php70u-iconv
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First please check that all install all extensions that PHP for
   Magento Require.
2. Then do this step:

You can try this:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer install
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

or you can remove `composer.lock` and then ran above command.

Hopefully this may help you